# How to print values of multi-value ()Drupal) Paragraph fields in separate columns

Tags: twig, drupal-8, paragraph

I have two fields in a custom paragraph type, Person. Each instance of paragraph type holds two values, that is, it will include two persons/people. I am working on the theme of the type (paragraph--person.html.twig). I would like to display to display each record in separate columns. Person 1 should be in Column 1 and Person 2 should be in Column 3.

Name of paragraph type - person
Person fields - field_name, field_bio
The person paragraph type is included in Page node type

Here is what I have tried.

```
   <div class="row">
 <div class="col-4"> Column 1 {{ content.field_name.0 }}
   {{ content.field_bio.0 }}
 </div>
 <div class="col-4"> Column 2 </div>
 <div class="col-4"> Column 3 {{ content.field_name.1 }}
   {{ content.field_bio.1 }}
 </div>
```

The result is nothing is printed in Column 3 and the row is repeated. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need to be altering the field template rather than the paagraph template as it would be the entity reference field (which references the paragraphs) that would be set to multiple values.
If you have [twig debug mode](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates) on, you should be able to see the name of this template in the html source.